# Magento: grabbing N number of products given a category ID

Tags: magento

I'm using the following code to  load all of the products with a search-view given a category ID:

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
        ->getProductCollection() 
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 3);
```

Is this possible to grab a certain number (N) while making this call? Right now, I load everything in `$categoryId` and just grab what I need, but it would be good if I can just load the desired number of products from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `->setPageSize();` like this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection() 
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 3)
    ->setPageSize(10);  // load 10 products
```

Comment: Do you know if I can also retrieve products by date created? It looks like it's matter of using `addAttributeToFilter` with the right column header?

Comment: Hey Sean, also, when you call `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')`, does that load from the flat data or the `_entity` table? There is an option in the admin that let you "use flat" data, and I'm wondering if this is related to the `getModel` call.